# Django visitor counter for overall website/app not for any specific object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am a python/Django newbie. I managed to deploy a Django based website based 'somehow' to save my job :). I know this has already been answered on SO but I couldn't get things working. I want to expand it and would like to start with a visitor counter to show what impact I made to my company. My current website is hosted on RHEL 7 using Mysql, mod_wsgi, Django 1.10, Python3.5. Is there any visitor counter with complete guide which doesn't need a lot of work to set up? Any recommendations? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good Django app for that purpose called [django-hitcount](https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount)

It tracks the number of hits/views for chosen objects. It's easy to use.

You should checkout the [documentation](http://django-hitcount.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Being a noob, it is tough for me to implement it. That's why I was looking for a full description of installation somewhere.

Comment: The current release is not compatible with Django 1.10 or Python3.5. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use Google analytics for best performance. If you want it in your django app, 
[django-hitcount](https://django-hitcount.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) may be helpful for your project.